# google storage cloud upload file using php

Tags: php, ftp, cloud, google-cloud-storage

Are there any cloud services out there that will allow automated uploading using FTP through PHP? I would like to use Google Cloud Storage if possible.

What I am trying to achieve is running a `cron` `mysql-dump` that on completion will automatically move the result file to a cloud storage giving a backup of the database on a separate server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to just backup a cron job, you could consider using a non-FTP utility like `gsutil`. Your cron job would have two steps: create a backup file with mysql-dump, and then upload that backup file using gsutil.

There are some third party programs that translate between cloud storage services and FTP, but I don't know of any cloud storage systems that support FTP directly.